# Element not interactable issue with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm fairly new with Selenium and I've been running a couple of very small web scraping projects.
When I try to click on this element through the  `.click()`  function I keep getting "Element not interactable"

The html section I'm trying to interact is this:

```
<a class="hawk-iconBefore hawk-styleCheckbox hawk-styleList" data-options="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;finish&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Foil&quot;}" href="https://starcitygames.com/search/?card_name=Glimmervoid&amp;finish=Foil" rel="nofollow"><span class="hawk-selectionInner">Foil <span class="hawk-facetCount">(5)</span></span></a>
```

And my python code looks like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver                    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  


url = 'https://starcitygames.com/'

card_name = 'Fatal Push'
expansion_name = 'Double Masters'
foil = True
card_price = 0

browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser_options.add_argument("headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=browser_options)
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(0.2)
browser.maximize_window()

print(card_name)

def get_card_price():
    global card_price
    print("Finding card...")
    browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='search_query']").send_keys(card_name)
    search_button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-submit")
    search_button.click()

    if foil:
        print("Checking if Foil...")
        foil_select = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[1]/main/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a")
        try:
            foil_select.click()
            print("It's Foil")
        except:
            print("Element not interactable")

    cards = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"hawk-results-item")
    for card in cards:
        c = card.text
        price = card.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='hawk-results-item__options-table-cell hawk-results-item__options-table-cell--price childAttributes']")

        if expansion_name in c:
            card_price = price.text
    return card_price

get_card_price()
print("Fetching card price...")
print(card_price)


browser.quit()
```

All other part send the info I need but when I check it the condition foil is true it jumps to the exception due to the element not being interactable.

I have tried accesing it with **css_selector**, and with the regular **xpath**, I saw another answer in which they suggested using the **full XPATH** and that it fixed the issue but it didn't work.

What could I do?

Comment: Are you sure that the element you select `foil_select` is the correct element ? Did you check its attributes ? Also, to work around this issue you could try to just find the element, get the link and tell your browser to change your current page.

Comment: To be honest I am not entirely sure if it's the correct one since it's inside a list but I have tried accessing the parent element as well as the span that it's after. Also I have tried looking on how to get the link and change the page but I haven't find it in the documentations for selenium, any clues where I can get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
browser_options.add_argument("headless")
```

should be

```
browser_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

You need to scroll to each cards first before grabbing the price.

Below is the sample code:

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://starcitygames.com/'

card_name = 'Fatal Push'
expansion_name = 'Double Masters'
foil = True
card_price = 0

#browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#browser_options.add_argument("headless")
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=browser_options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.2)
driver.maximize_window()

print(card_name)

def get_card_price():
    global card_price
    print("Finding card...")
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='search_query']"))).send_keys(card_name)
    search_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-submit")))
    search_button.click()

    if foil:
        print("Checking if Foil...")
        foil_select = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#hawkfacet_rarity li a[data-options*='Rare']")))
        try:
            foil_select.click()
            print("It's Foil")
        except:
            print("Element not interactable")
    time.sleep(5)
    cards = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hawk-results-item']")))
    for card in cards:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", card)
        c = card.get_attribute('innerText')
        print(c)
        price = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::div[contains(@class, 'price childAttributes')]")
        print(price.text)
        if expansion_name in c:
            card_price = price.text
    return card_price

get_card_price()
print("Fetching card price...")
print(card_price)
```

**Output:**

```
Fatal Push
Finding card...
Checking if Foil...
It's Foil
Fatal Push (Borderless)

Double Masters - Variants

Near Mint -
English
$14.99
QTY: 0
NOTIFY ME
$14.99
Fatal Push (Borderless)

Double Masters - Variants (Foil)

Near Mint -
English
$14.99
QTY: 3
Add to cart
$14.99
Fetching card price...
$14.99

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Wouldn't your idea fetch the price for each item? I figured that if I fetch the href for the item I want I'll get just the specific price for the one card I want. Also, does your idea might run faster than the one I published? I was planning on optimizing a little bit after solving this.

Comment: Well you are getting a href from an anchor tag, and you are traversing to that url, I think you will likely get stale element exception, for larger data. My code is already optimized with explicit waits. Eventually you will have to switch to explicit wait.

Comment: Moreover in your original post, you never mentioned that you would look for an href, original post was all about element not interactable error.

Comment: You're right. I decided to try that approach (href looking) as another user suggested but I will definetely try your solution as soon as I can. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to fetch the href for the element I wanted and it was as simple as just getting that and then telling my code to go to that page and execute the rest of the code:

That's how it looks now:

```py
if foil:
        print("Checking if Foil...")
        try:
            foil_select=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hawkfacet_finish"]/li[1]/a')
            link = foil_select.get_attribute("href")
            print("It's Foil")
            browser.get(link)
        except:
            print("Element not interactable")
    else:
        foil_select=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hawkfacet_finish"]/li[2]/a')
        link = foil_select.get_attribute("href")
        print("It's not foil")
        browser.get(link)
```

Now to move on with the next step. Thanks everyone!